# poker probability question not sure

Tags: probability, statistics, poker

i am confused with what does the question mean drawing two cards showing same number from one suite?

i figured it would be:
13C2 * 4C1 * 4C1 * 31C4 / 53C5?

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands#Two_pair

Answer (score 1):

The normal definition of two pairs does not mention suits at all.  You just need two each of two different numbers, like $2,2,4,4,5$.  You can't have two cards with the same number and suit because there is only one of each card in the deck.  I would read it that they are requiring that the fours have the same two suits as the twos, but that is not usually required.

Comment: does that mean my answer is right?

Comment: No.  As I am reading it, your $13C2$ picks the ranks of the pairs.  Then there should be $4C2$ to pick the suits of the higher pair.  The suits of the lower pair are now determined.  In the usual definition there would be another $4C2$ to pick the suits of the lower pair.  There are $44$ other cards to choose from for the fifth card.  The denominator should be $52C5$.